# Алгоритмическая "база" хорошего программиста. Вопрос по саморазвитию.

Tags: алгоритм

**Какие Алгоритмы Стоит Изучать?**

Вот, чем  я руководствовался, задавая этот вопрос:

Почти любой работодатель хочет увидеть хорошую алгоритмическую "базу". Так же эта "база" нужна и на практике. Но, какой должна быть эта "база"? Какие алгоритмы изучать?
Да, можно набросится на бесконечное множество всех алгоритмов и изучать их. Но их слишком много,что бы реализовывать их программно. Поэтому, на реализацию забивать приходится.

Мне этот путь не нравится. Думаю не только мне. Попытался найти в интернете подобные списки, но нашел лишь советы людей - "Кто знает, что вам пригодится?", "мне хватает знания сортировки пузырьком" и так далее.

Читать разнообразные книжки, такие, как Кнута.. Там опять же много алгоритмов. Пробежаться и забыть не хочется- хочется, что бы знания остались. А осваивать все-во первых долго, во вторых многие из этих алгоритмов представляют лишь теоретический интерес и на практике не применяются.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Полный список, конечно, составить невозможно, поэтому пробегусь по тому, что мне кажется важным.

1. Сложность алгоритмов. Вы должны знать O-нотацию и уметь сходу оценивать O-сложность алгоритма хотя бы для простых случаев.
2. Структуры данных! Не только простые структуры, типа массива, но и сложные: вы должны представлять себе, что происходит при добавлении элемента в красно-чёрное дерево (`std::map` из C++), и понимать, почему добавление в него быстрое.
3. Сортировки. Простые (надо знать и понимать недостатки и достоинства пузырьковой сортировки) и сложные (понимать хотя бы quicksort, и уметь на пальцах объяснить его идею).
4. Алгоритмы работы с деревьями: например, различные их обходы.
5. Поиск в графе: в ширину и в глубину, алгоритм Дейкстры и A*. Бинарный поиск в отсортированном массиве, конечно.
6. Математика! Матричные алгоритмы (детерминант, решение системы линейных уравнений не через детерминанты), преобразование между системами счисления (включая смешанные). Работа с рекуррентными последовательностями: вычисление степени и `n`-ого числа Фибоначчи за логарифмическое время. Мне ещё пригодились когда-то нахождение выпуклой оболочки и векторные трюки (типа расстояния между скрещивающимися прямыми через векторное произведение), но они нужны всё-таки реже.
7. Базы данных важны. Вы должны представлять себе, как выполняются JOIN'ы и какая «стоимость» материализации того или иного VIEW. Вы должны понимать, как строятся индексы, сколько они «стоят», и как они помогают. (В терминах O-нотации.)
8. Анализ игр может пригодится. Например, построение множества выигрышных позиций «с хвоста».

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил матрицы. И хотя бы базу по дискретной алгебре.
А так конечно +1 за ответ.

Comment: @SilverIce: я ещё дописываю :-) Если вспомнится ещё, добавляйте к себе в ответ, может, получится неплохой список.

Comment: @VladD. 7. - мне иногда кажется, что серьезный проектировщик БД, нагруженные, распределенные, многопользовательские проекты - это религия ))

Comment: @SilverIce: Ага, так что надо знать её основы, чтобы при столкновении с её адептами не удивляться :)

Answer (score 12):

Большинство работодателей которых интересует "алгоритмическая база" на самом деле были латентными извращенцами, которые хотели показать, давая вам кривую олимпиадную задачу, как необозримо круты они, и как малы и латексны все вокруг)) С вопросами оплаты и карьерного роста потом тоже были проблемы.

На самом деле львиную долю народа интересует в нанимаемых программистах три вещи:

- умение быстро доучиваться и творчески решать задачи;
- умение писать качественный код - то есть не содержащий багов, не содержащий ошибок в безопасности, не содержащих глупых ошибок, которые снижают быстродействие;
- умение приспосабливать к работе в команде.

Алгоритмы - хорошо. Но общее понимание, что такое сортировка, что такое индексирование, как лучше хранить данные, чтоб это было оптимально по затратам и доступности, как лучше построить цикл (какие действия нужны внутри, а какие можно вынести вне), какие могут быть ошибки в данном коде, и как их нужно экранировать и обработать. Какие данные могут подсунуть пользователи на вход по дури, а какие по злому умыслу - и как максимально обезопасить код от ошибок внешних данных. Вот это с точки зрения хорошего программиста важнее.

Алгоритмы как таковые вам понадобятся в трех случаях:

- вы трудоустраиваетесь в иностранную контору, где анализируется квалификация вцелом - но тесты обычно построены так, чтоб понимать, понимаете ли вы в общем о чем это - ну и дочитали ли вы Кнута, Седжвика, Вирта, Страуструпа до конца);
- вы трудоустраиваетесь в контору, которая пишет низкоуровневый софт, вот тут как раз вы можете нарваться на то, что многие из алгоритмов, которые "представляют лишь теоретический интерес и на практике не применяются", ещё живи и здравствуют;
- вы устраиваетесь в контору, которая пишет софт для моделирования, графики и 3Д движки))

Кстати, как утверждают знакомые, работающие в последней категории знание физики вцелом, предметной области, а также алгебры, геометрии, матанализа и умение щелкать пятиэтажые уравнения (причем правильно) - им нужно гораздо чаще, чем Кнут.

Диверсификация знаний и навыков, как по мне, так же полезна, как и доходов ;)

Answer (score 8):

По совету [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd) преобразовал комментарий к его ответу тоже в ответ.

Я бы добавил:

Понимание компиляции-интерпретации-линковки (тут же (кроме линковки) сидят регулярные выражения и тоже надо бы понимать как их алгоритмы устроены).

Представление о работе с дисками (теперь еще и с флэшем). 
В этом плане полезно знать как работает внешняя сортировка.

Еще на эту же тему - когда индексный доступ к данным в базе полезен, а когда наоборот, только замедляет выполнение запроса.

Ну и как LAN (TCP/UDP/ICMP и т.п.) работает. Тут в первую очередь надо познакомится с сокетами.

Еще одна модная теперь тема это потоки (threads) и соответственно синхронизация доступа к памяти. Тут же вспомним о процессах и алгоритмах межпроцессного взаимодействия.

К алгоритмам напрямую не относится, но желательны определенные познания в области современных архитектур компьютеров. Прежде всего конвейеризация исполнения команд, предвыборка команд и данных, внеочередное исполнение, кэши процессора и проблема когерентности кэшей в SMP и NUMA архитектурах, порядок величин времени задержек при обращении к кэшу и RAM, а также организация виртуальной памяти (разделение функций между аппаратурой (MMU, TLB) и ОС), принципы обработки прерываний (тоже, что делает железо, а что ОС).

(*если еще  что-то хорошее (или о чем спрашивали меня или спрашивал я) вспомню, то буду добавлять сюда*)