# Собеседование по алгоритмам - как подготовиться к нему за одну неделю?

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте.

Примерно через неделю мне предстоит собеседование по алгоритмам.

У меня незаконченное математическое образование, что означает, что я знаю, что такое, например, логарифм или факториал, но при этом совершенно не имею академической подготовки по этой теме (толкового курса по программированию и по этой теме в частности в течение 3 лет, что я учился, не было). Мой суммарный опыт программирования - 4 года. Основные языки в настоящее время Objective-C и C.

Я пытаюсь продумать оптимальную стратегию для подготовки и поэтому интересуюсь: **может ли кто-нибудь набросать что-то вроде обзора этой темы "Алгоритмы" (quick overview), ориентируясь на который можно было бы более или менее направленно успеть за неделю пройти самые-самые основные в этой теме вопросы?**

Вот навскидку то, что мне известно в связи с этой темой (точнее о чём имею более или менее чёткое представление, список неисчерпывающий):

- O-notation
- Хорошо знаю примерно треть алгоритмов из этого репозитория: [EKAlgorithms](https://github.com/EvgenyKarkan/EKAlgorithms) и даже кое-что добавил туда сам, например, алгоритмы Indexes of maximum and minimum elements simultaneously, Quickselect, Partial selection sort, алгоритм бинарного поиска.
- Например, хорошо теперь знаком с geo-spatial структурами и алгоритмами вроде: KD-деревья и двумерные K-деревья в частности, Quad-деревья, алгоритмами Grid clustering и K-means.
- Например, хорошо знаю, как устроены массивы и словари в C и Objective-C, включая circular buffer (который лежит в основе [массивов NSMutableArray у Apple](http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/03/05/exposing-nsmutablearray/)).
- ...

Одним словом, общее представление у меня точно есть, но всё-таки очень часто я сталкиваюсь с отсутствием академических знаний - например, только на днях узнал о таком понятии, как "амортизированная стоимость" или, например, недавно, понял, что не понимаю, почему при подсчёте алгоритмической сложности некоторых алгоритмов возникает именно десятичный алгоритм (то есть, откуда берётся именно 10 в основании).

Потенциальных авторов ответов я прошу именно об обзоре, а не об ответах со ссылками на известные многотомные работы по алгоритмам, осилить которые у меня по определению нет времени.

Буду благодарен за законченные, целостные и сбалансированные ответы, которые помогут мне или другим потенциальным читателям этого топика, так как, уверен, тема эта актуальна всегда и везде.

P.S. Особо интересно было бы увидеть ответ @VladD.

---

Хороший соседний топик (из ответа @VladD) - [Алгоритмическая "база" хорошего программиста. Вопрос по саморазвитию.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/262661)

---

Спасибо.

Comment: Если не секрет, на какую должность вы идете?

Comment: @Russtam, примерно - "Разработчик мобильных приложений под iOS".

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но, мне казалось, что в сложности не десятичный логарифм, а логарифм по основанию 2, просто записывается как log.

Comment: Ну вот и нашёлся пример про употребление именно __lg N__: [Быстрая сортировка](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0). Цитаты (можете просто поискать lg):

> ...Ожидаемое время выполнения алгоритма сортировки составляет O(n lg n)...

> ...что гарантирует глубину рекурсии не более lg(N)...

> ...Зато глубина рекурсии ни при каких обстоятельствах не превысит O(lg n)...

Я уже предположил в другом комментарии свою версию про такие случаи: невнимательность или незнание авторов (скорее первое).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_time#Logarithmic_time

> Due to the use of the binary numeral system by computers, the logarithm is frequently base 2 (that is, log2 n, sometimes written lg n).  

и вообще, как правильно заметили, O(lgN)=O(lnN)=O(logN)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, спасибо за ссылку. Выходит, эта небрежность является ещё и стандартом. Вы же понимаете, что утверждать 

> O(lgN)=O(lnN)=O(logN)

это достаточно рискованно в общем случае?! Понятно, что там отличие на константу, но всё же путать математические обозначения, сознательно или бессознательно... хм... не вижу ничего хорошего! Я после прочтения Вашей ссылки решил взять за правило писать хотя бы log N, но уж никак не lg N, несмотря на то, что эта небрежная форма употребления в интернете встречается достаточно часто.

Comment: это не небрежная формула, это написание кем-то когда-то принятое, достаточно одной популярной книжке про O нотации выйти и цитаты из нее будут в википедию пихать, ничего удивительного.  
Согласно стандарту двоичный логарифм надо обозначать как `lb N` ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-11)это если в ISO 80000-2 не поменялось), но никто так не делает, потому что никому это не нужно.  
А в O нотации *не указывается* основание, ибо оно и не важно (с точностью до константы), и не является математической записью, а лишь показателем логарифмической сложности.

Comment: и да, про равенство O от разных логарифмов не рискованно. В этом смысл O-нотации, потому что рассматриваются предельные случаи.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, я с Вами полностью согласен во всех пунктах! Я скорее в данном случае пытаюсь само-определиться с тем, какой нотации следовать __мне__, а какой избегать, и выходит, что лично я точно не буду употреблять __lg N__ до тех пор, пока речь не зайдёт про именно десятичные алгоритмы. Я предположу, что не только я подзастрял вниманием на этой теме с __log N vs lg N__, и лично я рад, что удалось это прояснить! Ещё раз спасибо за меткую ссылку именно про это.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: Ну вы ж информируйте нас о том, как идёт подготовка, хорошо?

Comment: Ну как успехи, коллега?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

По этой теме как-то было обсуждение: [Алгоритмическая "база" хорошего программиста. Вопрос по саморазвитию.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/262661/10105)

Приведу выжимку, которая мне кажется важной и подходит для креш-курса:

1. Сложность алгоритмов, O-нотация, нужно уметь сходу оценивать O-сложность алгоритма хотя бы для простых случаев. Туда же Θ-нотация.
2. Структуры данных: деревья, обходы их, trie, куча, разрежённые матрицы и всё такое. Про них любят спрашивать.
3. Сортировки. Про них, скорее всего, не спросят, так как все знают и готовятся. Но всё же.
4. Графы, различные их представления и работа с ними. Поиск в ширину и в глубину, алгоритм Дейкстры и A*.

Обязательно попрактикуйтесь с разными задачами. Алгоритмы могут означать некую олимпиадную составляющую, но туда лучше не заглядывать, очень уж специфическая область умений (если вы только сами не оттуда).

---

На интервью не бойтесь сказать, что вы чего-то не знаете. (Это всё равно довольно сложно скрыть.) Но останавливаться и проваливать часть интервью не стоит, просто скажите, что вы попытаетесь сходу что-нибудь придумать. Ну и попробуйте придумать, это зачтётся.

---

Мне кажется, не стоит тратить последнюю неделю на поиск и усвоение новых знаний: новый багаж должен утрястить, прежде чем вы сможете его эффективно использовать. Поэтому лучше

- систематизируйте имеющиеся знания, если есть видимые пробелы (например, та же «амортизированная сложность» в hashtable), заполните их. Вероятно, имеет смысл задать их отдельными вопросами здесь и на математике.
- прогоните хорошую серию задач, чтобы чувствовать себя уверенно.
- настройтесь на то, что не только работа нужна вам, но и вы — работе: адекватный работодатель возьмёт вас, если увидит, что вы интересуетесь темой и растёте над собой (даже если каких-то знаний на момент интервью нет), а неадекватный вам и не нужен.

Comment: А ещё, я бы погуглил "algorithms interview", и порешал задачи оттуда. Теория-теорией, а практика расшвыривания задач навскидку тоже пригодится.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за ответ. Буду следить за обновлениями. Про algorithms interview - да, есть такое в планах.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: Странно, почему возникает десятичный логарифм. Может, двоичный? Впрочем, поскольку двоичный и десятичный отличаются на постоянный множитель (`lg x = log_2 x / log_2 10`), то с т. зр. асимптотики (О-нотации) они не отличаются.

Comment: @VladD, в том то и дело, что странно. Так как я знаю, что отличием можно прнебречь, я предполагал, что часто пишут `lg N` тогда, когда или 

1) четко не знают отличие между ними, но пишут `lg N`, когда, например, хотят указать на "logarithmical lookup time" (встречал, например, в связи с массивами). 

2) знают, но действительно пренебрегают и пишут `lg N`. 

Позже, если интересно, я поищу такие материалы в интернете, где упоминается исключительно `lg N`, например, в отношении массивов или словарей (даже встречал на каких-то задачках просто).

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, Вы на собесседовании на основании логарифма лучше внимание просто не заостряйте.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, вижу. Я в целом тоже так смотрю на процесс подготовки с небольшой разницей лишь в том, что вдобавок ещё выборочно смотрю два курса по Алгоритмам: один [Coursera, вроде как Princeton](https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partI) и курс Яндекса: "Алгоритмы и структуры данных поиска".

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, обратите внимание на совершенно правильное замечание @VladD об адекватности работодателя.

Скажем, меня бы больше интересовало не знание конкретных алгоритмов и их особенностей, а общее представление соискателя о существовании разработанных алгоритмов (и м.б. их сложности) для той или иной сферы.

Answer (score 10):

> Ну вы ж информируйте нас о том, как идёт подготовка, хорошо?

Пришло время написать немного о подготовке и результатах - конечно же я собирался это сделать и уже давно, просто ждал пока придёт ответ от компании. Теперь ответ пришёл, и я могу теперь спокойно закрывать гештальт.

Расскажу в нескольких частях. Ничего интересного не обещаю. Особенно более опытным, чем я, участникам ХК.

Итак,

**I. Материалы и источники, которыми я пользовался.**

- Книга Cracking the code interview, 5th edition.
- Лекции Яндекса: "Алгоритмы и структуры данных поиска. Бабенко Максим Александрович." (торрент)
- Видео-курс "Robert Sedgewick, Kevin Wayne - Algorithms"(торрент) и их книга `Algorithms (fourth edition)`.
- Репозиторий с простейшими алгоритмами на Objective-C: [EKAlgorithms](https://github.com/EvgenyKarkan/EKAlgorithms), одним из контрибьюторов которого я являюсь. В основном я больше привношу в этот репозиторий, чем беру из него - среди прочего я постоянно добавляю варианты к уже существующим там алгоритмам и добавляю к ним тесты так, чтобы можно было легко проверять как уже имеющиеся варианты, так и новые варианты и легко сравнивать их между собой, в том числе по производительности. Кроме того, я стараюсь максимально оптимизировать и гуманизировать (humanize) все находящиеся там алгоритмы, чтобы их можно было легко и быстро адаптировать для использования в реальных Objective-C/Cocoa программах.

---

**II. Подготовка.**

Подготовка происходила сумбурно и, имея в виду разумное напутствие VladD:

> Мне кажется, не стоит тратить последнюю неделю на поиск и усвоение новых знаний: новый багаж должен утрястить, прежде чем вы сможете его эффективно использовать... (и далее весь раздел)

- Я посмотрел первые три лекции Яндекса: "Сложность и модели вычислений", "Анализ учётных стоимостей", "Функции быстрой сортировки и сортировки слиянием". Там я впервые узнал, например, про тета- и гамма- нотацию. Также внимательно слушал про "анализ учётных стоимостей" (амортизированная стоимость, метод банкира и др.). Послушал про сортировки - сравнение основных методов, стабильность, in-place, итд. Например, впервые узнал, но почти ничего усвоил - только смутное представление - про сортировку внешних данных External memory Merge Sort и K-way merge.
- Прочитал около сотни страниц Cracking the code interview - особой пользы практической в связи с алгоритмами я, конечно, не получил, но зато появилось некоторое представление о том, что там происходит в компаниях "большой шестёрки" с точки зрения code interviews. Например, среднее количество собеседований в этих компаниях примерно 6-8 штук, но это все кроме меня тут наверняка знают.
- Посмотрел выборочно несколько видео-лекций из курса Седжвика про сортировки и особенно остановился на его разборе быстрой сортировки - видео мне показалось мало, и я проглядел ещё и книгу, раздел про Quick Sort. Среди прочего удивило то, что только в 1990 году некий инженер из Bell Labs заметил, что quick sort начинает работать очень затратно на последовательностях с большим количеством одинаковых ключей (у него это были нули и единицы), и только после этого qsort в stdlib был исправлен для того, чтобы это учесть. Сюда же утверждение Серджвика о том, что в начале нужно делать рандомайз всего массива, чтобы гарантировать беспорядок, чтобы было `N * log N`. Словом, было интересно, и я все эти моменты отметил.
- Во время прослушивания лекции Яндекса про `merge sort` меня привлекла идея о том, что при слиянии двух кусков можно обойтись `N / 2` дополнительной памяти (`external storage`) вместо `N` (я думаю все кроме меня тут в курсе, о чём речь). Меня это сильно увлекло, и я решил закрепить этот принцип на практике и тут же поправил процедуру построения К-деревьев в библиотеке `kingpin` - там используется немного другая идея, но аналогия была очень точной и получилось сделать то самое [сокращение temporary storage в 2 раза](https://github.com/itsbonczek/kingpin/pull/27). Я квалифицирую это приключение, как решение задачи в количестве 1 штука в духе

> прогоните хорошую серию задач, чтобы чувствовать себя уверенно.

как советовал @VladD.

- Меня давно заинтересовала задача Иосифа ([Josephus Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem)), и я в течение двух-трёх дней из этой недели небольшими подходами пробовал решить её в качестве ещё одной из задач для разминки перед собеседованием. Признаюсь честно, сделать [efficient-версию с O(K * log N) вместо O(N)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845260/josephus-for-large-n-facebook-hacker-cup) ума не хватило даже совсем приблизительно, от чего до сих пор есть чувство собственной неполноценности - хватило только на наивную версию (как в Википедии) и версию, в которой используется "итератор-убийца" - она работает медленно, но зато позволяет хорошо визуализировать ход того, как происходят убийства.
- Повторно изучал очень хороший, основанный на дизассемблировании, [разбор](http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/03/05/exposing-nsmutablearray/) того, как внутри устроен класс NSMutableArray - это класс для мутабельных массивов в Cocoa. В его основе лежит Circular buffer, но кроме этого простого факта в статье содержится ещё несколько деталей, которые очень полезно знать именно Objective-C разработчикам.
- Добавил некоторое число алгоритмов в EKAlgorithms (главным образом, сортировки), поправил реализацию уже существующих там (написанных не мной), написал несколько тестов для того, чтобы проверить некоторые нюансы изучаемого материала.
- Так как кроме собеседования по алгоритмам ожидалось ещё одно собеседование по iOS, то я готовился ещё и по теме iOS - читал все основные источники в основном по двум темам: Run loops, Autorelease pools.

Основное вроде всё описал, двигаюсь дальше.

---

**III. Собеседование.**

Перед самым собеседованием настроение было такое, что меня уничтожат вопросами про деревья, графы, матрицы, про многочисленные изобретения Эдсгера Дейкстры и прочее. Вышло же всё совсем просто, хотя я всё равно 1! раз умудрился продемонстрировать незнание самых простых именно азбучных основ [из-за их отсутствия я собственно и открывал этот вопрос пару недель назад].

Итак:

Первым вопросом было рассказать о общем о том, как измеряются сложность и эффективность алгоритмов. Я рассказал самые простые и тривиальные вещи. Вопрос был общий и простой.

Дальше было уточнение про O-нотации. Я тоже рассказал всё в общем адекватно и, как мне кажется, хорошо.

Следующим был задан вопрос про то, что именно обозначает O-нотация (подразумевалось в сравнении с тета-, гамма-) - тут я честно застрял, так как эти детали у меня совершенно вылетели из головы - я честно признался, что помню лишь, что одна из них "сверху", другая "снизу", третья "снизу и сверху", но какая из них какая, не знаю чётко. Считаю это главным своим недочётом во всём собеседовании.

Был вопрос именно про то, что мы обсуждали здесь про lg N, а именно: "А какой именно логарифм имеется в виду, когда говорится о логарифмической сложности?". Я конечно же рассказал всё то, что мы успели затронуть здесь - и о строгой математической нотации и о том, что log2 и lg асимптотически отличаются друг от друга на константу, о том, что скорее всего **lg N** просочилось в массовое употребление с подачи нескольких классических работ по алгоритмам. Словом, ответ был очень развёрнутый. Можно считать это замечательным совпадением, так как открывался этот топик в том числе для ответа на этот вопрос - "почему встречается lg N, если имеется в виду log N или точнее log2 N?".

Дальше был общий вопрос рассказать про Quick Sort - я тут же восторженно рассказал обо всём, что с большим интересом наизучал по видео и книге Седжвика и своим экспериментам с имплементацией всего им описанного: про 1990 год, про рандомайз, чтобы убрать худшие случаи, про откат к insertion sort'у на малом числе элементов. Как мне показалось, своим рассказом я "грузанул" своего собеседователя так, что следующим, что он предложил, было написать "что-нибудь попроще" на его компьютере в коллабедите (в котором присутствовал также второй собеседователь) простой Bubble Sort, что я и сделал мгновенно с использованием лаконичных Cocoa API. Меня попросили прокомментировать написанное, что я и сделал. Всё было правильно.

Дальше вступил второй собеседователь и спросил про худшие случаи для Bubble Sort и спросил, как можно их смягчить. Я сходу, по следам рассказа про худшие случаи в Quick Sort, ответил, что если такие худщие и редкие для Bubble Sort случаи действительно ожидаются, можно делать перед началом сортировки рандомайз. Мой ответ устроил спрашивающего, но он спросил: "А ещё?". Я подумал некоторое время и понял, что сходу сказать не смогу (я всегда в таких случаях точно могу оценить, сколько времени мне точно *не* хватит для решения задачи, и это был такой случай). Оба собеседователя сошлись на "ладно, хорошо" и попросили рассказать на словах про Selection Sort и Insertion Sort. Я чётко рассказал про Selection Sort и начал рассказывать про Insertion Sort - начав немного путаться, я попросил времени подумать. Первый собеседователь сказал: "ладно, у нас остаётся мало времени, давайте решим задачу".

Задача оказалась такой: есть генератор random01(), который в случайном порядке выдаёт нули или единицы. Нужно на его основе написать random0123(), который выдаёт случайные 0 или 1 или 2 или 3.

Не успев даже подумать про первый и второй биты целого числа, в каждый из которых записывается по random01() (это понимание уже пришло после собеседования), я сразу увидел геометрическую аналогию с задачей про [выбор квадранта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/306437/c-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8), которую мы недавно разбирали с @avp, @paulgri, @VladD и @mega, и тут же сказал, что нужно просто взять random01() два раза в две переменные, а потом использовать двойное ветвление, и показал собеседователю эту геометрическую аналогию. Я сказал, что будет честно считать, что я эту задачу знаю и что можно попробовать решить какую-нибудь ещё. Он спросил меня, "а как сделать на основе random01() троичный random012()?", то есть как из 2 получить 3 случайных числа, а не 4, как в первой задаче, но тут нас начали выгонять из переговорной. Я решил эту задачу уже дома, и понял, что будь на собеседовании больше времени, я бы не догадался о решении за отведённое малое время. Я отправил своему собеседователю это решение просто как follow-up, так как всегда выполняю нерешённые задачи в качестве "домашнего задания".

Вот и всё.

---

**P.S.**

А итог такой, что меня не взяли. Причины отказа не назвали, сославшись: "У нас не принято сообщать о причинах отказов" и только: "Фидбэк о вас очень положительный, но продолжить общение мы не сможем".

Было 4 собеседования:

1) Вводное с ведущим разработчиком. Про это рассказывать долго, отмечу основное:

Я очень грамотно рассказал о наивных имплементациях NSMutableArray, NSMutableDictionary в том виде, как они описаны Mike Ash в его известных постах "Let's build NSMutableArray" и "Let's build NSMutableDictionary" - я очень хорошо знаю эти реализации с С массивом позади NSArray и простейшим словарём позади NSDictionary, так как делал кое-какие вещи на их основе. В процессе рассказа был вопрос про амортизированную стоимость - я на тот момент об этом не знал совершенно, даже слов таких не слышал, о чём и сказал прямо. Кстати, это "жесткое незнание" было одной из причин открытия этого вопроса.

Ещё была простейшая задача на матрицу вида N * N, которую я не решил в отведённое время, запутавшись с индексами - я не предложил ответ, а так и сказал, что запутался. Это наверное, был единственный серьёзный прокол за все 4 собеседования. Мой ответ собеседователю был такой: "я чётко понимаю, что мне нужно больше времени на эту задачу, в пределах этого времени у меня нет решения". В самом деле, придя домой, я решил эту задачу за 5 минут, так как в этой задаче для её быстрого решения нужно было "всего лишь" догадаться об одной очевидной мелочи (кавычки потому что "эх, если б сразу, вовремя").

2) Собеседование по iOS.

Типичные вопросы. Отмечу некоторые:

- Вопросы про разницу instancetype и init.
- Написать геттеры/сеттеры к данным @property (под MRC)
- NULL, nil, Nil, NSNull - кто такие, и в чём разница.
- Вопрос про блоки, в котором подразумевается знание о необходимости копировать блоки, чтобы копировать их содержимое на heap.
- Проверка на знание Cocoa-паттерна:

  - (void)aMethod:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error {
    // do stuff, possibly assigning error if something went wrong
    }

3) Алгоритмы (о них я рассказал выше).

4) "Архитектура". Я предполагал, что это будут вопросы про архитектуру, то есть устройство iOS, оказалось, что это собеседование про проектирование - меня спросили как спроектировать библиотеку для единой авторизации, которую смогут использовать несколько родственных между собой мобильных приложений. Чуть позже выяснилось, что мои собеседователи в этом интервью сами как раз являются разработчиками этой функциональности для всей экосистемы мобильных приложений в этой компании.

---

**P.S. №2**

Не уверен, зачем я написал этот длинный пост. Наверное цели <del>три</del> две: <del>люблю печатное слово</del> первая - закрыть для себя вопрос с большим первым раундом подготовки по теме алгоритмы, вторая - возможно, вдруг кому-то хоть как-то написанное окажется интересным или полезным - лично я, пожалуй, был бы не прочь прочитать такой текст перед началом собственной подготовки к аналогичной цепи собеседований.

---

Comment: жаль, что не взяли, вы достаточно упорный и адаптивный, интересно что им надо было ? Думаю самое простое объяснение - возвращение блудного попугая (человек который незадолго до того уволился, а потом вернулся).

Comment: > жаль, что не взяли,

@eicto, спасибо! Доброго времени суток))

> интересно что им надо было

теряюсь в догадках))

> вы достаточно упорный и адаптивный

Первый раз слышу такую характеристику "адаптивный" - наверное, это что-то скорее положительное?

Comment: ну да, типа можете достаточно быстро прошарить некую область по запросу, хорошее и редкое качество.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: не взяли? Ну и бог с ними, подавайтесь к следующим.

Во-первых, ни в коем случае не расстраивайтесь, причина не взять может быть самая дурацкая, как правильно отметил @eicto. То есть им же и не повезло. Во-вторых, самое сложное — первая работа, дальше будет проще, опыт работы и портфолио заруливает всё на свете (по крайней мере, тут в Германии). В-третьих, вы прекрасно подготовились, и теперь следующее интервью будет намного легче.

Короче, одни плюсы.

Comment: Прочитав ваш пост я понял, что меня никогда не возьмут на работу. О_о

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, а Вы в местную фирму шли или в иностранную? А то может просто с языком что-то не понравилось?

А потом, говорят, что Эйнштейн никогда бы не смог устроиться на работу к Эдиссону (по требованиям, которые предъявляли там к соискателям). Так что, присоединяюсь к остальным, не расстраивайтесь.

Comment: Кстати, если увлекаетесь сортировками, то пару лет назад я заинтересовался, можно ли сделать устойчивую сортировку с временем O(N log N) и дополнительной памятью меньше O(N). (Получилось или нет -- это, конечно, вопрос).

В результате написал вариант сортировки слиянием (назвал **yamsort**). Посмотреть можно [тут](http://code.google.com/p/yamsort/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk) yamsort.c, yamsort.h и yamsort_tmpl.h. По критерию "байтосекунды" (на первый взгляд довольно странному) она оказалась среди лучших.

Там еще куча сортировок и программа measure.c  для их сравнения.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: кстати, по идее, наихудший случай для пузырьковой сортировки — это когда массив отсортирован в противоположную сторону, т. к. понадобится в точности N-1 проход (после каждого прохода неотсортированная часть будет отсортирована в противоположную сторону, а на место упадёт ровно один элемент), а за такое к-во проходов любой массив будет гарантированно отсортирован (т. к. за один проход неотсортированная часть сокращается на по крайней мере 1 элемент).

Answer (score 7):

Вдобавок к ответу [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd):

1. Деревья: балансировка деревьев
2. Комбинаторика: способы оценки трудоемкости алгоритмов (отсюда и вытекает О-нотация)
3. Матрицы: обращение треугольной матрицы, обращение 2-3-х диагональных матриц (это хит)
4. Олскульные ребята (вроде меня) обожают вопросы связанные с решением задач на экономию  ресурсов (обычно память): кэширование, рекурсия vs. массив, LRU списки, битовые маски, хэши и проч.

Поищите в сети книжку [Cracking Coding Interview](http://www.crackingthecodinginterview.com/content/table-contents) - полезно полистать.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Советую прочесть книгу - Карьера программиста. Она небольшая но очень познавательная и полезная в данном вопросе.